# Trouble getting field value from firebase collection

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I am new to ionic 4 and typescript and have started a project that uses firebase as its database. I created a collection called 'cost' with a field 'perKm' and value 5. I have been attempting to use AngularFirestore (import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore') to get and edit the field value. I have tried looking at tutorials but they deal with pull collections with large data sets and not a single value. How may I be able to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: add your code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in Firestore for you to just fetch a single field of a data, the smallest chuck of data that you can request is a whole document which contains that specific field.

Then you can modify the data object of the document on that specific field and using `update()` method on document to apply your desired changes.

Documents in Firestore by nature should not contain big piece of data, and it is recommended to keep them as small as possible while designing the data model.

Make sure to check [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/master/docs/firestore) out if you are using AngularFirestore